# What is a word that means pitches above (or below) the range of human perception?

Tags: single-word-requests

See the title. This would be analogous to "ultraviolet" and "infrared" for color.

Comment: [Ultrasonic.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ultrasonic)

Comment: Colloquially, "dog whistle", which also has a specific connotation in describing US politics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sonic describes sounds. So you would use Ultra or Infra combined with Sonic.

**Ultrasonic**(ul-tra-son-ic):

> of or involving sound waves with a frequency above the upper limit of human hearing.

**Infrasonic** (in-fra-son-ic):

> relating to or denoting sound waves with a frequency below the lower limit of human audibility.

Both definitions come from the Oxford Dictionary of English.

Comment: Please add citations for these definitions.

Comment: " Thanks to Katy Payne **...**  discovery of infrasonic communication..." <http://elephant.elehost.com/>

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean ***[ultrasound](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ultrasound):***

> - (General Physics) ultrasonic waves at frequencies above the audible range (above about 20 kHz), used in cleaning metallic parts, echo sounding, medical diagnosis and therapy, etc.

Collins Dictionary